# How to prevent Microsoft Small Business Server Active Directory addresses showing up in OSX Address Book?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, mac-osx, g-suite, windows-sbs

A client has MS Small Business Server installed and numerous iMacs and MacBooks in their office which staff use.  They use Google Apps for Business for email not Exchange.

Their IT guy needed to set up some 'pseudo' accounts for some reason - name@*remote*.domain.com.  These aren't valid email addresses - just accounts that he needed to set up for some function required in SBS, but are - misleadingly - very similar to the real Google Apps email addresses: name@domain.com (i.e. minus the '*remote*')

The issue they're having is that these invalid addresses are appearing in the staff Mac address book under "Directory Services".  And frequently these invalid addresses are selected when composing emails and thus get delivery failure notifications.

My question is how can I prevent these invalid addresses from being picked up by OSX Address Book / Mail?  I appears that I need to disable the relevant Directory Services settings using */System/Library/CoreServices/Directory Utility.app* but I can't see anything relevant there.

Comment: If they are configured in Exchange, you can hide them from the Address Book, but it sounds like you are talking about Directory Services.  Why/how are the macs querying AD?  If all you email is done through AD, then you shouldn't need to have AD being queried for email.  Another option that might work would be to remove the account's email address in AD, if you aren't using exchange, then odds are you might not need the email address in there.  (Though you should probably verify this first)..